# Declaring module is causing lint error 'Unexpected token, expected "{"'

Tags: typescript

I created the file `omnivore.d.ts` to get typescript to ignore that this library has no types available. In the file I have the line

```
declare module '@mapbox/leaflet-omnivore'
```

When I run `vue-cli-service lint` on my project it raises an error on the line

```
error: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{"

> 1 | declare module '@mapbox/leaflet-omnivore'
    |                                          ^
```

I did some searches and I see other posts including an object after the string but I can't see what I should add in this case. From what I can tell there is nothing functionally wrong with this code because the page seems to load and work fine but its failing my CI because of this lint error.

Comment: You can start from adding `{}`

Comment: @AlekseyL. That gives a new lint error `Empty block statement (no-empty)`

Comment: So you can add some typings or disable this rule for that line

Comment: @Qwertie Try adding semicolon (;) at the end of your declare statement (`declare module '@mapbox/leaflet-omnivore';`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it to

```
declare module '@mapbox/leaflet-omnivore' {/* empty */}
```

which is what eslint suggests for blocks that are meant to be empty.

Comment: aren't you getting lint error while importing from  '@mapbox/leaflet-omnivore' ?

Comment: Yeah @Avinash I get a lint error in my import/usage of classnames with this approach. It does fix the initial error, but creates a new one. `This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("classnames")' has no call signatures.ts(2349)`

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when I started with `lint-staged`,
why I indicated only the end of extensions `*. {js, jsx, ts, tsx}`,
forcing lint to check all files that have them.

This worked for me:
Add the `!` Operator to an extension you want to ignore:

It's working!

```
{
 "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}, !*.d.{ts}": [
      "yarn run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```